# Unity, show different logo on different platforms in code

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to show a different logo on **Windows** and **Linux**. I test in windows, but build for Linux.
How can I do this without having different code files and builds.

```
  public void ShowLogo()
    {
        if (isOpen == true)
        {
            //Logos are both off by default

            //Show In Linux??
           // linuxLogo.SetActive(true);

            //Show In Windows??
           // WindowsLogo.SetActive(true);
 
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out platform dependent code compilation.

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PlatformDependentCompilation.html

```
public void ShowLogo()
{
    if (isOpen == true)
    {

        #if (UNITY_STANDALONE_WIN || UNITY_EDITOR)

        WindowsLogo.SetActive(true);

        #endif


        #if (UNITY_STANDALONE_LINUX)

        linuxLogo.SetActive(true);

        #endif

    }
}
```

Comment: Just a note that when you select the compilation platform on Unity, the editor will then see that the current selected platform as the current platform. ie. if you are building for OSX and you are working from Windows and you set the build platform as OSX the the current platform dependent compilation will use OSX. You can use the || UNITY_EDITOR to see the results in editor.